# How do I go about Counting the number of stack frames within my frameCount function?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, backtrace, stack-frame

I have assembly code, called by frameCount, and need to return frameCount, but unsure how to retrieve (then navigate) previous frame's pointer reference.

getFP.s

```
  .globl getFP
getFP:
  movq %rbp, %rax
  ret
```

frameCount.c

```
int frameCount() {
  int count = 0;
  uint64_t fp = getFP();
  uint64_t *sp = &fp;
  
  // how do I get the pointer/offset to pointer to the previous stack frame from here?
  
  return count;
}
```

## Update:

I've updated the frameCount function to include a loop that traverses the linked list of stack frames, but I'm getting a segmentation fault when calling frameCount.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include "framecount.c"

int main() {
  printf("Number of Frames: %d\n", frameCount());

  return(0);
}
```

frameCount.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint64_t* getFP();

int frameCount() {
  uint64_t* fp = getFP();
  uint64_t registerValue1 = *fp;

  while (registerValue1 != 0) {
    printf("current register value %" PRIx64 "\n", registerValue1);
    printf("next register value %" PRIx64 "\n", *(volatile uint64_t *)registerValue1);
    count++;
    registerValue1 = *(volatile uint64_t *)registerValue1;
  }

  printf("count=%d\n", count);

  return count;
}
```

Output

```
current register value 7ffca7c147b0
next register value 401230
current register value 401230
next register value 8d4c5741fa1e0ff3
current register value 8d4c5741fa1e0ff3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

However, when I do the following I don't get a segmentation fault, but the count seems incorrect:
(update: removed bogus example)

## Update 2:

Still getting a segmentation fault even when running with option `-O0` or `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` Here's the assembly output from initial first update:

```
    .file   "lab7.c"
    .text
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "%d"
    .text
    .globl  frameCount
    .type   frameCount, @function
frameCount:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    getFP
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rax
    movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rax
    movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
.L2:
    cmpq    $0, -16(%rbp)
    jne .L3
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   frameCount, .-frameCount
    .section    .rodata
.LC1:
    .string "Number of Frames: %d\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    frameCount
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    $.LC1, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 10.2.1 20200723 (Red Hat 10.2.1-1)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: Your last program is bogus because you are walking the stack starting with the `%rbp` from `NewFunc3` after it has already returned.  The chain of frame pointers on the stack may have been overwritten by then.

Comment: Your first updated version works for me with `gcc -O0` and returns a count of 1 as expected.  Note that `frameCount` is not counting itself in the call chain.  As I noted, if you compile with optimizations, you should expect it to fail with a segfault or otherwise.  What compiler and options did you use?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm using gcc 10.2.1 just tried to compiled with command `gcc -O0 -g -Wall -std=c99` and it still gives segmentation fault.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce that.  gcc 10.2.0 on x86-64 Linux here.  Some compilers might be configured to omit the frame pointer even with `-O0`; does it help if you add `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`?  You could also look at the generated assembly (use `-S`) and see if it is indeed using the frame pointer.

Comment: @NateEldredge I updated my question with the generated assembly. I wasn't able to get it working with the `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` unfortunately.

Comment: @NateEldredge here is the repl https://repl.it/@obiy/l7#framecount.c

Comment: At lines 13-14 of your `framecount.c` in the repl, you set `prevValue = registerValue1;` and then test whether they are unequal.  This is of course always false so you never enter the interesting part of the loop.

Comment: A couple general comments, while I'm thinking of them: (1) don't include .c files into each other.  Write a header with declarations only, which you include; compile the .c files separately, and link them.  (2) A function with no arguments in C is declared like `int getFP(void);`, not `int getFP();`.  The latter declares a function with *unspecified* arguments.  In particular, the compiler thinks it could be variadic, and so it has to jump through some extra hoops to call it (if you're wondering why there are apparently unnecessary zeroings of `%rax` before all function calls, that's why.)

Comment: Anyway, your code in the repl also seems to be trying to loop until it finds an frame pointer that points to itself.  That is not the correct termination condition; as I stated in my answer, at the end of the list you will find zero.  If you don't test for that, you will dereference it and segfault.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225211/discussion-between-yibo-and-nate-eldredge).

Answer (score 7):

**In general this technique will not work.**  Walking stack frames like this is only possible if the compiler actually uses them.  On x86-64 under Linux and similar OSes, this is not required by the ABI, and is not the default for most compilers when optimization is enabled, though on GCC and clang you can request it with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`.  But if some of the functions in the call chain were using `%rbp` for something else when they called the next function, the stored `%rbp` will not point to the previous one and your program will probably crash.  There is an alternative way to walk the stack using unwind info stored elsewhere in memory, but it is complicated, so people often use a library like [`libbacktrace`](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace) instead.

However, when stack frames are in use: you can look at [how a compiler sets them up](https://godbolt.org/z/rPx74W):

```
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
```

Since the x86 `push` instruction decrements `%rsp` and then stores the pushed value at the new address where `%rsp` points, the `movq %rsp, %rbp` leaves `%rbp` containing the address where the previous `%rbp` is stored.  The top of the stack frame has an `%rbp` value of 0, so you can simply do something like

```
for (uint64_t *fp = getFP(); fp; fp = (uint64_t *)*fp) count++;
```

Comment: I ran your code and do get a segmentation fault. I've updated my question with additional details.